# print_req_error: I/O error, dev sad, sector xxxxxxxx

Tags: 18.04, kernel, virtualization

I have Ubuntu server running on Freenas as a VM using Bhyve.  After upgrading the Ubuntu server, it is just constantly printing `[xxx.xxxxx] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sad, sector xxxxxxxxxx`.  Before these error messages, it reported errors starting some services, etc. but I didn't have time to capture those errors before it started constantly printing `print_req_error...`.  I have performed an upgrade a lot of times before without any issues.  The server was running fine before the upgrade.

Output from the upgrade:

```
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Fetched 88.7 kB in 2s (44.9 kB/s)
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.15.0-88-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.15.0-88-generic
Replacing config file /run/grub/menu.lst with new version
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

After the upgrade I've rebooted Ubuntu, and those errors started being reported.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4.

I can use Freenas VNC to see the server output, but I can't stop the `print_req_error` output or boot into 'safe mode', as the startup/grub menu is not shown.  The Freenas disk pool is not showing any errors indicating a HDD failure.

What can I do to fix this and get my Ubuntu server running again?

Comment: FreeNAS is not based on Ubuntu. Also, I would check the hypervisor and not the VM for Hardware related errors

Comment: @StrabagISS_Krall, I'm using Freenas as a host for my Ubuntu server VM.  I've checked the ZFS pool on Freenas, which contains the volume for the VM -- no hardware errors reported and Freenas runs fine, including other VMs/Docker containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that exact same issue. 
Actually even creating a new VM with 4.15.0-96-generic will crash.
On one VM i was able to boot in "safe mode" and revert back to linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic by doing 
sudo apt-get remove 4.15.0-96-generic
then I set to 4.15.0-91-generic to boot and brought my VM back.

I don't think it's a Ubuntu issue but more of a freenas/freebsd issue towards Linux.

Hope you didn't trash your VM's zvol thinking that the issue was there, like i did.

Comment: that's exactly what I did and I can boot my Ubuntu server VM without issues now.  Not sure why 4.15.0-96 fails to boot.  Thanks

Comment: Quick update, I also had a vm with a desktop Ubuntu, running on 5.3.0-46 and it's frozen as well. When i try booting using older images (5.3.0-45 or -42) I still get the same issue.
All i can do is boot in recovery mode, with each but I think the last update of FreeNAS might've "broken" something.
I keep editing this one.. I think i found the root cause:

https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/ubuntu-virutal-machine-no-longer-works.83737/
It's got to do with bhyve rather than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. After digging around I found users with a similar problem on the iXSystems forums: https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/ubuntu-virtual-machine-no-longer-works.83737/

The fix recommended there was to shut off the VM, then edit the disk device, and switch it from AHCI mode to VirtIO. After following those steps the I/O errors went away for me and I was able to use the VM (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS).